# How to alter a header setting for mobile views?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner trying to display a different header on a mobile screen. The header has a background image portrait of 4 people, which will be too narrow so people will be left out when viewing on mobile.

What I tried is setting the background size to 100%, but this means there is a gray space below the picture (which is now fully visible) on mobile.

```
smallheader {
    background: url(../image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 70px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 0;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #139cb0;
```

Decreasing the height to 300px on a mobile screen would work. How can I edit the code, or add a new class so that I can edit this height for mobile screens?

Comment: what have you tried so far? The easiest approach would be the use of `media queries`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 430px){
     smallheader {
        background: url(../image.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center 70px;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        z-index: 0;
        border-bottom: 15px solid #139cb0;
    }
  }
```

use media query like this

Comment: Thank you, this looks great. Should I add this to the same CSS file as the original header or do I have to place it somewhere else?

Comment: its a media query so i place all the media queries at the bottom of the CSS you can do the same